# TEMP Tablespace Removal

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, tablespaces

Oracle Version: 12.1.0.2

We have a discrepancy between our PROD and DR **TEMP** tablespace data files.

- `PROD = 30G + 30G + 30G` data files
- `DR   = 30G + 30G + 30G + 21G + 2G + 1G + 15G` data files

I want both my environments to only have the 30 GB **TEMP** tablespace data files only (In total 90 GB). I need to remove the additional `21G +2G +1G +15G` tablespace data files in the DR environment.

It is critically important for me to know who added the other non standard tablespaces. Do we have a query to find the culprit?

Also: How safe is it to remove the other non-standard TEMP tablespace data files? Is there a safe way or an Oracle defined process to do that?

Comment: Do you have `AUDIT` enabled? Personally, the question "can you find the culprit?" (an `AUDIT` question), should be in a separate post then "how do you remove files from a `TEMPORARY TABLESPACE?".

Comment: Well, The primary concern is on how to remove the TEMP in an orderly fashion. Something you can do to help?

Comment: The general concept that I would use is:  move everyone to temporary tablespace `TEMP2`.

Comment: Everyone? Thats a good idea for standalone non standbys. I agree 100% but are you sure i can attempt that on a standby?

Answer (score 1):

The alert log will show what user added a data file to your DR tablespace, but most likely they logged on as `SYS / AS SYSDBA` instead of a user that has SYSDBA privileges (one more reason to assign roles to users, especially DBAs.  The alert log is usually in `$ORACLE_BASE/diag/${ORACLE_UNIQ_NAME}/${ORACLE_SID}/trace/alert_${ORACLE_SID}` (I may have those ORACLE_UNIQ_NAME and ORACLE_SID backwards).

To clean up the DR TEMP tablespace, just create a new TEMP tablespace TEMP2, alter the database to use the new temporaray tablespace, drop the old TEMP tablespace, then rename the new temp tablespace TEMP2 to TEMP:

```
create temporary tablespace temp2
  tempfile '/some_dir_path/temp2_01.dbf' size 30g,
  tempfile '/some_dir_path/temp2_02.dbf' size 30g,
  tempfile '/some_dir_path/temp2_03.dbf' size 30g
;

alter database default temporary tablespace temp2;

drop tablespace temp including contents and datafiles;

alter tablespace temp2 rename to temp;
```